# setting position of one activity in middle of two activities using viewpagerindicator

Tags: android

I am working with viewpagerindicator
I have 3 activity namely FirstActivity.java SecondActivity.java and ThirdActivity.java

Code for FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);



    return v;

}
```

}

Code for SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);



    return v;

}
```

}

Code for ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, null);



    return v;

}
```

}

Code for FragmentAdaptor.java

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment = new FirstActivity();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstActivity();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondActivity();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdActivity();
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    String title = "";
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        title = "First";
        break;
    case 1:
        title = "Second";
        break;
    case 2:
        title = "Third";
        break;
    }
    return title;
}
```

}

SO from this code i get my default page to FirstActivity.java and other two activity in the right side.
**i want my second activity in the middle of two pages when the app starts.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`. You can take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) for more information

In your `Activity.onCreate()` method you will do something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter());
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Comment: where should i call viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)  
Can you please implement in the code above.
Thankyou.